# How do I preconfigure Gradle Plugin Repository?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I want to use new fancy `plugin { id: ''}` syntax in Gradle with my custom in-house plugins that are stored in company's Artifacotry. In order to do this I can set maven repository for Gradle Plugin Repostiory in [settings.gradle only](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:custom_plugin_repositories).

I want to set this globally in my custom Gradle package that would be downloaded using Gradle wrapper. I can define globally dependencies repository and buildscript dependendencies repository in $GRADLE/init.d/repositories.gradle script, but I can not do it for Gradle Plugin Registry  because it is required to be placed in settings.gradle.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you find a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this using the [settingsEvaluated](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.invocation.Gradle.html#org.gradle.api.invocation.Gradle:settingsEvaluated(groovy.lang.Closure)) method from the Gradle API.

Put the following in an init script.

```
def ENTERPRISE_REPOSITORY_URL = "https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/repo"

settingsEvaluated { setting ->
    setting.pluginManagement.repositories {
        // Remove all repositories not pointing to the enterprise repository url
        all { ArtifactRepository repo ->
            if (!(repo instanceof MavenArtifactRepository) ||
                repo.url.toString() != ENTERPRISE_REPOSITORY_URL) {
                project.logger.lifecycle "Repository ${repo.url} removed. Only 
                        $ENTERPRISE_REPOSITORY_URL is allowed"
                remove repo
            }
        }

        // add the enterprise repository
        maven {
            name "STANDARD_ENTERPRISE_REPO"
            url ENTERPRISE_REPOSITORY_URL
        }
    }
}
```